# Where is the file systems table in OS X?

Tags: mount, macos

I can see the following mounts on my MacBook:

```
> mount
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
```

Where are these configured? I see this file apparently does nothing:

```
> cat /etc/fstab.hd
IGNORE THIS FILE.
This file does nothing, contains no useful data, and might go away in
future releases.  Do not depend on this file or its contents.
```

If this file "does nothing", what configures all the things that are currently mounted on my system?

Comment: What are you trying to do with /etc/fstab (i.e. is there a application to the knowledge) or are you just seeking a tutorial on the inner workings of the boot process that mounts the 4 entries at boot time?

Comment: @bmike the latter